# Non-linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, export, series-expansion, nonlinear, canonicalization

I have to solve this equation but the problem is X is function of x it means `X[x]`

$$X(X-a)+ b e^{-2 X t}=B,$$

a,b,B are constants.

How we can I get some result for this equation? Plot as well `X(x)` but `x` is also function of `t`.

Comment: Couldn't find a small `x` in your equation?

Comment: X is X[x] I believe...but I don't understand what the OP wants for a solution....or what they intend to plot with unknown constants.

Comment: From the context of the question I think the desired quantity is X(x(t)) and then plot it vs t... This is just a speculation though

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You need to formulate better. There is `X`, `x` and `t`. It is not clear what is a function what, and what needs to be found.

Answer (score 4):

The OP seems maybe to want `X` as a function of `x`, but the OP gives up an equation that defines `X` as a function of `t`.  No good clue about how to incorporate `x` into the solution `X[t]` as defined by the given equation.

Here's one way to go about finding `X[t]` numerically.  The equation has a 3-parameter family of solutions, so we seek an order-3 differential equation for the family.  This turns out to be easy.  Next we need to find initial conditions for `X[t0]`, `X'[t0]`, `X''[t0]` in terms of the parameters `a`, `b`, `B`.  This is easy if `t0 = 0`.  We get two solution components `psolM`/`psolP` because the initial condition for `X[0]` is a quadratic equation (`M` for minus √, `P` for plus √).

```
eqn = X[t] (X[t] - a) + b Exp[-2 X[t] t] == B;

sys = NestList[D[#, t] &, eqn, 3];

ode = Eliminate[sys, {a, b, B}];

ics = Solve[Most@sys /. t -> 0, 
   NestList[D[#, t] &, X[t], 2] /. t -> 0];
Length@ics (* number of solutions = 2 *)
(*  2  *)

{psolM, psolP} = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, #}, X, {t, -2, 2}, {a, b, B}, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"] & /@ (ics /. Rule -> Equal);

nosol = Verbatim[ParametricFunction][___][___] -> 
   Interpolation[{{-2., Indeterminate}, {2., Indeterminate}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Manipulate[
 Quiet@ListLinePlot[{psolM[a, b, B], psolP[a, b, B]} /. nosol, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-5, 5}}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Pane[Style[$MessageList, "Label"], {320, 60}, 
     Alignment -> Center]],
 {{a, 1}, -4, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {b, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{B, 4}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica cannot solve your equation for X .
Instead try to solve it for t

```
sol=Solve[X (X - a) + b Exp[-2 X t] == B, t ][[1]] /. C[1] -> 0(*forces real solution*)
(*{t -> Log[b/(B + a X - X^2)]/(2 X)}*)
```

Now you know t as a function of X.
For examplary parameters you can plot the result

```
ParametricPlot[{t, X} /. sol  /. {a -> 1/5, b -> 1, B -> 3/2}, {X, -2,2}, AxesLabel -> {t, X}]
```

[image]